# Prove existence positive integers $\epsilon <|h\sqrt{m}-k\sqrt{n}|<2\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given positive integers $h,k$ and $\epsilon>0$ show that there exist positive integers $m,n$ so that the inequality $\epsilon<|h\sqrt{m}-k\sqrt{n}|<2\epsilon$

Comment: You should provide some context for your question: is it coursework or something else? Answers are more effective when we know why you asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can even achieve $\epsilon< h\sqrt{m}-k\sqrt{n}<2\epsilon$, without absolute value. 
Begin by considering the curves $h\sqrt{y}-k\sqrt{x}=\epsilon$ and $h\sqrt{y}-k\sqrt{x}=2\epsilon$  in the positive quadrant of the $xy$-plane. It helps to present them as graphs of functions: $y=f_1(x)=((\epsilon+k\sqrt{x})/h)^2$, and similarly for the other, $y=f_2(x)=((2\epsilon+k\sqrt{x})/h)^2$. Then consider the difference $f_2(x)-f_1(x)$ and show that it grows indefinitely  as $x\to\infty$. Therefore, $f_2(x)-f_1(x)>1$ for all sufficiently large $x$. Conclude that there is a point with integer coordinates between these two curves.

Answer (score 1):

This is [problem B1](http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnam/-pdf/2011.pdf) from the 2011 Putnam competition. [One solution](http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnam/-pdf/2011s.pdf) is on the [MAA Putnam website](http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnamindex.shtml).