# Simple inequality using density of rationals

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, triangle-inequality

The problem:

> Let $h$ and $k$ be positive integers. Prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there are positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that
> $$
> \varepsilon<|h \sqrt{m}-k \sqrt{n}|<2 \varepsilon
> $$

My approach: note it suffices to find $\frac{m}{n} \approx \frac{k^2}{h^2}$. Because the latter is a real number, we can use the density of the rationals to approximate it arbitrarily well, and so in particular we can find an $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ that is a $2\epsilon$-approximation, but not an $\epsilon$-approximation. I am trying to formalize this intuition. I know the triangle and reverse triangle inequalities will probably be needed. I'm starting from the fact that I know that I have an $m, n$ such that $\frac{m}{n} \in [\frac{k^2}{h^2}, \frac{k^2}{h^2} + \epsilon]$, and trying to conclude, but am unable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove existence positive integers $\epsilon \lt |h\sqrt{m}-k\sqrt{n}| \lt 2\epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305848/prove-existence-positive-integers-epsilon-h-sqrtm-k-sqrtn2-epsilon).

Comment: Also duplicate of [Let $h$ and $k$ be positive integers. Prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265277/let-h-and-k-be-positive-integers-prove-that-for-every-epsilon-0)